# FSK modulation in baseband

Tags: digital-communications

In a $4$-FSK we have

$$s_i(t)=\cos(2 \pi f_i t)=\cos(2 \pi (f_c+\alpha_i \Delta f)t)$$

with $\alpha_i=2i-5$, and $\Delta_f=\frac 1T$, where $T$ is the time symbol and $i \in [1,4]$.

But with the expression of $s_i$, I have a bandpass signal. To get the baseband signal: $g_i(t)=e^{j2 \pi f_i t}$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The expression $g_i(t) = e^{j2\pi f_i t}$ is not the baseband signal--- it is simply the positive frequency portion of your bandpass signal. To convert this to a baseband signal we need to take the further step of frequency translating the modulated signal centered about the carrier frequency $f_c$ to baseband $f=0$ as follows:

$$f_b = g_i(t)e^{-j 2\pi f_c t} = e^{j2\pi f_i t}e^{- j 2\pi f_c t} = e^{j2\pi (f_i-f_c)t}$$

$$= e^{j 2 \pi (f_c+\alpha_i \Delta f - f_c) t)} = e^{j2\pi \alpha_i \Delta ft}$$

This is further demonstrated with the spectral plots below showing the difference between a passband and baseband signal:

[image: spectrum]